# Basic Properties of Integrals

Tags: measure-theory

I am doing a course on measure theory and we are studying integrals and there is a lemma which states:

$\int f$  $d\mu$ exists and is greater than $-\infty$ if and only if $\int f^{-} d\mu$ $< \infty$. And there is no proof for this either, so I am confused as to what this means and why it is true.

(In case people don't notice, in the second integral there is a minus sign on top of $f$ and $f^{-} = \max(0, -f(x))$)

Comment: Don't you mean $f^- = \max(0, -f(x))?$

Comment: oh god, yes, of course, cant believe I made such a stupid error

Comment: Also, a piece of advice for the future: when writing certain mathematical functions, like max, it's better to write them like so: `$\max$` (producing $\max$ which is nicer than `$max$` (producing $max$).

Comment: What is definition of existence $\int f\, d\mu$ ? I thought the integral first is defined for $f>0$.

Comment: The statement is not true if existence of the Lebesgue integral is understood as absolute integrability.<br> Take $f(x):=x^2$ then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^{-}(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$ but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x=\infty$.

Comment: Well i thought $\int f$ exists whenever f is a measurable function on $X$ where $X$ is any fixed space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue integral is first defined for non-negative functions. Then the definition is extended to general functions without sign constraint. In particular, writing the function as $f=f^+-f^-$, one defines $\int f=\int f^+-\int f^-$, where $f^+$ and $f^-$ are positive and negative parts which are non-negative functions. So for Lebesgue integral to make sense, apriori one needs both $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ to be finite.

Sometimes as convention, when $\int f^+=+\infty$ and $\int f^-<+\infty$, we say $\int f=+\infty$; or when $\int f^+<+\infty$ and $\int f^-=+\infty$, we sat $\int f=-\infty$.

There are, however, examples where $\int f^+=+\infty$ $\int f^-=+\infty$ in the Lebesgue sense, but one can make sense of $\int f$ by taking limit $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-a}^a f$. For example $f(x)=|x|^{-1/2}\sin(x)$.